# Replace single Column value in Datatable based on Row and Column Id

Tags: c#-4.0, model-view-controller, datatable

I have been working on DataTable in my MVC5 application, and there is a requirement that i need to replace particular Column value of a row in Datatable with new value, i have got Row and Column id number with Updated value. But i need a simple way of replacing old value with new value.
This is what i have tried so far:

```
 public ActionResult Change(int RowId, int ColId, string NewValue, string OldValue)
 {            
    if (NewValue != OldValue) 
    {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            //Here i will store value from session
            dataTable = Session["Table"] as DataTable;

            //Here i'll get entire Single Row record from the Data Table based on Row Id
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.Rows[RowId];

            //Now i want to get column value by providing Column Id
            //DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn("ColId");
            //Here i'll store new value for that column
            dataColumn = NewValue;

            //Now Replace or Save new column value back to Datatable
            //dataTable.Columns.Remove("ColId");
            //dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
     } 
     return View();
}
```

Can anyone help me in saving/Replacing new Column value of that particular column in Row and back in Datatable.

I Solved this by using this code:

```
public ActionResult Change(int RowId, int ColId, string NewValue, string OldValue)
 {            
    if (NewValue != OldValue) 
    {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            //Here i will store value from session
            dataTable = Session["Table"] as DataTable;

            //Here i'll get entire Single Row record from the Data Table based on Row Id
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.Rows[RowId];

            //This is what i used to do replace value
         if (Convert.ToString(dataRow[ColId]) == OldValue)
         {
            dataRow[ColId] = NewValue;
            dataTable.AcceptChanges();
            Session["Table"] = dataTable;
         }
     } 
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way to achieve this.

- table.Rows[RowId][ColId] = NewValue  (may need to write table.acceptchanges())

Comment: Perfect Single line solution compared to mine... Thank You